# ¿Como evitar condicionales anidados o switch-case inmensos? JAVA

Tags: java, condiciones, sintaxis

Supongamos que tengo un programa en el que según lo que quieras hacer, tienes que insertar un número correspondiente a esa función, algo así:

```
*presiona:
          1. para hacer tal cosa
          2. para hacer...
          3. etcétera...*
```

Lo primero que se me ocurre para verificar la opción elegida, y ejecutar el método correspondiente, es un switch-case. Sin embargo, si las opciones en vez de ser 3, fueran 10 o más, el switch-case seria inmenso. La pregunta es:
¿Hay alguna alternativa -en java- para evitar estas estructuras que terminan siendo molestas, desprolijas y difíciles de entender? ¿O son un "mal necesario"?

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

supongamos que tienes un switch de esta forma

```java
switch(opcion){
  case 1:
    // ...20 lineas de código
  break;
  case 2:
    // ...30 lineas de código
  break;
  default:
    // ...10 lineas de código
  break;
}
```

lo que puedes hacer es simplemente una función que haga todo lo que necesitas para cada opción y asi tienes mas limpio tu código

```java
switch(opcion){
  case 1:
    this.pressOpcion1();
  break;
  case 2:
    this.pressOpcion2();
  break;
  default:
    this.pressOpcion3();
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Planteamiento

Lo que he entendido de tu pregunta es que no quieres estar añadiendo continuamente el `case x: .... break;` y quieres algo más dinámico

La mejor manera es realizar un objeto donde contenga los métodos y luego utilizar `getMethod` y `invoke` para coger el método y ejecutarlo. De esta manera **solo tendrás que preocuparte de que exista el método**

Para ello he creado una clase llamada `customSwitch` donde tiene todos los métodos

### Resolución

```java
customSwitch objeto=new customSwitch();
//Aquí añado los métodos que pueden existir o no existir
String[] metodos = {"5","2","0"};
//El for sobre los metodos existentes
for(String metodo : metodos) {
    try {
        //Aquí llamo al método con metodo + el string del array
        //El invoke puede llevar parámetros al método, pero mis métodos no llevan 
        //parámetros así que lo establezco a null
        customSwitch.class.getMethod("metodo"+metodo).invoke(null);
        //Para acceder a un metodo no estatico deberás de añadir el objeto de
        //customSwitch al .invote. Comento como quedaría:
        //customSwitch.class.getMethod("metodo"+metodo).invoke(objeto,null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Control de si existe o no existe el método
        System.err.println("No existe el metodo");
    }
}
```

**Objeto customSwitch**

```
public static class customSwitch{
    public customSwitch(){}
    public static void metodo0(){
        System.out.println("0");
    }
    public static void metodo1(){
        System.out.println("1");
    }
    public static void metodo2(){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
}
```

### Salida

```java
run:
No existe el metodo //Método 5 no existe
2                   //Método 2
0                   //Método 0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: El problema que me surge, es que necesito implementar metodos que no pueden ser "static". Y si no son "static", la linea `customSwitch.class.getMethod("metodo"+metodo).invoke(null);` me da error

Comment: Para acceder a un método no estático en el invote debes de añadir el objeto de `customSwitch` creado previamente. Quedaría tal que así: `customSwitch.class.getMethod("metodo" + metodo).invoke(obj,null);`. Lo añado a la respuesta como comentario